# Dependency installation error in GitHub Actions

Tags: nestjs, github-actions

I'm uploading the changes in NestJS via GitHub Actions.

Until yesterday, all code works normal.
But today's code is an error.

```yaml
steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      # Initialize Node.js
      - name: Install Node.js 18
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 18

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          yarn install       <------------------ error
```

Below is an error message.

```
error This project's package.json defines "packageManager": "yarn@3.6.1". However the current global version of Yarn is 1.***.21.

Presence of the "packageManager" field indicates that the project is meant to be used with Corepack, a tool included by default with all official Node.js distributions starting from 16.9 and 14.19.
Corepack must currently be enabled by running corepack enable in your terminal. For more information, check out https://yarnpkg.com/corepack.
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

I searched for an error message, but I couldn't get accurate information.

How do I make modifications to work normally?

Answer (score 3):

I deleted the following code from my `package.json`.

And all code works normal.

```js
"packageManager": "yarn@3.6.1" <--- remove
```

I don't know the exact reason.

It is necessary to confirm that checking in `Github Actions's policy` has changed.

Please let me know if there is a more certain way. thank you

Comment: https://yarnpkg.com/corepack yarn now requires each project to specify a yarn version, here's a read from them

Answer (score 0):

I think issue is with npm version . try  using v20.10.0

Answer (score 0):

So the reason is that yarn has changed how the cli works, we used to install it with `npm install -g yarn`, but they are now moving away from this approach, meaning each project would have its own yarn and yarn version. Checkout https://yarnpkg.com/corepack,

So, to fix this, either follow the steps on the link to enable corepack, or alternatively, if you disagree with them, just remove the key and value `"packageManager"` inside the project's `package.json`